# Mapping file works in release mode, not in debug mode (Visual Studio)

Tags: c, visual-studio, compilation, memory-mapped-files

I am trying to do a file mapping of my current process, following the MSDN documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-a-view-within-a-file

It appears that the mapping works when I compile in Release mode (in visual studio), but throws an error when I do in Debug mode :

```
> .\my_bin.exe
File path is : C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\my_bin\x64\Debug\my_bin.exe
Copying file using file mapping
error lpMapAddress is NULL : 5
```

5 is the error code for ACCESS_DENIED. I wonder why I would have an access denied on a binary I am executing myself, and to which I am asking READ_ONLY permissions.

If anyone has an idea, I would be thankful !

Here is the code:

```
#define handle_error(msg)                \
    do {                                 \
        printf("error %s : %d\n", msg, GetLastError()); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
    } while (0)


void file_mapping_copy(TCHAR* file_path) {
    HANDLE hFile;
    HANDLE hMapFile;
    LPVOID lpMapAddress;  // pointer to the base address of the
    BOOL bFlag;
    DWORD dwSysGran;      // system allocation granularity
    DWORD dwFileMapStart; // where to start the file map view
    DWORD dwMapViewSize;
    DWORD dwFileMapSize;
    SYSTEM_INFO SysInfo;  // system information; used to get granularity
    hFile = CreateFile(file_path,
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);
#ifdef _DEBUG
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        handle_error("Create File error");
    }
#endif

    GetSystemInfo(&SysInfo);
    dwSysGran = SysInfo.dwAllocationGranularity;
    dwFileMapStart = 0;
    dwMapViewSize = MAP_BUFF_SIZE;
    dwFileMapSize = MAP_BUFF_SIZE;

    hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(hFile,          // current file handle
        NULL,           // default security
        PAGE_READONLY, // read/write permission
        0,              // size of mapping object, high
        dwFileMapSize,  // size of mapping object, low
        NULL);          // name of mapping object

#ifdef _DEBUG
    if (hMapFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        handle_error("Create File error");
    }
#endif
    lpMapAddress = MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,            
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write
        0,                   // high-order 32
                             // bits of file
                             // offset
        dwFileMapStart,      // low-order 32
                             // bits of file
                             // offset
        dwMapViewSize);      // number of bytes
                             // to map
#ifdef _DEBUG
    if (lpMapAddress == NULL) {
        handle_error("lpMapAddress is NULL");
    }
#endif
    puts("should be ok");
    bFlag = UnmapViewOfFile(lpMapAddress);
    bFlag = CloseHandle(hFile);
#ifdef _DEBUG
    if (!bFlag) {
        handle_error("Close File error");
    }
#endif
}
int main() {
    WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, path, MAX_PATH);
    printf("File path is : %ls\n", path);

#ifdef _DEBUG
    puts("Copying file using file mapping");
#endif 
    file_mapping_copy(path);
}
```

**EDIT**: I mistaken the permissions of `MapViewOfFile`, which required FILE_MAP_READ permissions. Still, the error is weird.

Comment: Just a guess: In `CreateFileMapping`, you use `PAGE_READONLY` (i.e R/O). But, in `MapViewOfFile`, you use `FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS` (i.e. R/W). Otherwise, I've been told that in production mode, all uninitialized global space variables get zeroes [just like linux `.bss` segment]. But, in debug mode, they get some non-zero pattern designed to trip up access to a variable if it's not been initialized before use. Also, turn on full compiler warnings. Are there any uninited stack variables?

Comment: @CraigEstey
You are right about the `FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS`, indeed, I posted an EDIT 5mn ago.
Well there are many initialized stack variables indeed. I've been told that debug mode was initializing the memory to 0, while the release mode did not. Looks like this works the other way around. As the permissions were wrong but the file could map the first 0 (0's initialized memory I guess), I guess it did not thrown an error. This is total speculation, tho.

Comment: Like many cleaning people, I don't do windows :-). The WinX debug seeding was explained to me by another responder, and I could be wrong. But, if true, it makes uninited global data under WinX kinda useless as it requires explicit assignment before use [which posix et. al. doesn't]. If `_DEBUG` is _your_ define, you can force it on to get the extra error check. For me, I _always_ do `if (some_error) handle_error;`, so I might remove the `#ifdef _DEBUG` for these. (i.e. It might _not_ be _your_ code _directly_). Just print a global scalar in `.bss` in hex to see what the seed is for each mode.